# Onto homomorphism from G to Z21

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group such that a surjective homomorphism from $G$ to $\mathbb{Z}/21\mathbb{Z}$ exists. Prove that $G$ contains normal subgroups of index 3 and 7
I have seen a proof using the Correspondence theorem. However, we have no learned this theorem and cannot use it. I understand that I need to use the First Isomorphism theorem.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Construct surjective maps:

$$\begin{array} ~\mathbb{Z}/21\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \\ \mathbb{Z}/21\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}\end{array}$$